# LetsEncrypt with Apache2 Redirection

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am struggling with the https redirection of my domain. My domain is hosted with godaddy and my server is hosted with ionos. I was able to install the ssl certification and if I go directly on https:  //domain.com it is working as expected. Unfortunately, the redirection is not working at all.

the conf file looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@domain.de
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and the ssl conf file like that:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin admin@domain.de
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com [OR]
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I hope someone has an idea regarding this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, place it out of the virtualhosts (might not make a difference), and also make sure mod_rewrite is on.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Edit:
Added the flags R=301 and L for the redirect.

Info:
If the above doesn't work when you place it outside of virtualhosts, you should add the following after the `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteOptions InheritDown
```

Comment: Also remove or comment out the other rewrites for https redirect

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I still do not know what happened, but it is working now. I tested everything and just decided to set everything up again. Since the server was completely empty it was easy to do. Now it is working, the files are looking the same btw.

Comment: Also, I've changed the last line of code in my answer, so use the new one. please